# How to add a path parameter in a GET call using Restsharp?

Tags: c#, restsharp

I have the following url http://example-api.com/userid/1234
How can I added the 1234 path parameter to my URL.

the RestRequest class has AddParameter and ParameterType but I do not see any option for path parameter

```
   RestRequest.AddParameter(value, ParameterType.);
```

Comment: Also take a look at Flurl as an alternative to restsharp sometime, https://flurl.dev/docs/fluent-url/ i presonally prefer it (but thats more taste)

Answer (score 8):

Use `AddUrlSegment()`

https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#url-segment

```
var myParamValue = "1234"
var request = new RestRequest("http://example-api.com/userid/{myParam}")
    .AddUrlSegment("myParam", myParamValue);
```

Comment: docs have moved to:- https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#url-segment